# Correlation coefficient of convolution of two bivariate normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

If $f$ and $g$ are [bivariate normal PDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Standard_normal_random_vector) having correlation coefficients $ρ_f$ and $ρ_g$ respectively, what is the correlation coefficient of the bivariate normal distribution $h=f*g$, where $*$ denotes the convolution operator? I've tried searching for the answer but come up dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can determine the correlation coefficient without also knowing the variances, but you should be able to determine the new covariance matrix given the covariance matrices for $f$ and $g$. It can be shown that the distribution with pdf $h=f*g$ corresponds to the the distribution of $Z=X+Y$, where $X,Y$ are independent and have the respective densities $f$ and $g$. In particular if $X,Y$ are independent with $X\sim N(\mu_X,\Sigma_X)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$, then
$$X+Y \sim N_2(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\Sigma_X + \Sigma_Y),$$
and the correlation coefficient can then be determined from the matrix $\Sigma_X + \Sigma_Y$ as
$$\rho_Z = \frac{\rho_X \sigma_{X_1} \sigma_{X_2}+\rho_Y \sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2}}
{\sqrt{\sigma_{X_1}^2+\sigma_{Y_1}^2} \sqrt{\sigma_{X_2}^2 + \sigma_{Y_2}^2 }},$$
where
$$\Sigma_X = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{X_1}^2 & \rho_X \sigma_{X_1} \sigma_{X_2}  \\
\rho_X \sigma_{X_1} \sigma_{X_2}   & \sigma_{X_2}^2\end{pmatrix}
 \quad \text{ and } \quad
\Sigma_Y = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{Y_1}^2 & \rho_Y \sigma_{Y_1} \sigma_{Y_2}  \\
\rho_Y \sigma_{Y_1} \sigma_{Y_2}   & \sigma_{Y_2}^2\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ has pdf $f$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ has pdf $g$. Then if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X + Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2)$ has pdf $h$.

See [Help for convolution of two Multivariate Gaussian PDFs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471656/help-for-convolution-of-two-multivariate-gaussian-pdfs)